# Netbeans Cannot list file for Reason: 227 Entering Passive Mode

Tags: netbeans, ftp, netbeans-8.2, passive-mode

I am using remote server with netbeans 8.2 before that, but suddenly it stopped and gives me this error when i try to make synchronize.

> Cannot list file for Reason: 227 Entering Passive Mode.

In manage Remote Connections every thing looks good and by testing the connection it gives me this

> "Connection succeeded."

Output of Remote Log is like below.

```
220---------- Welcome to Pure-FTPd [privsep] [TLS] ----------
220-You are user number 1 of 50 allowed.
220-Local time is now 19:49. Server port: 21.
220-This is a private system - No anonymous login
220-IPv6 connections are also welcome on this server.
220 You will be disconnected after 15 minutes of inactivity.
USER ********
331 User ******** OK. Password required
PASS ******
230 OK. Current restricted directory is /
TYPE I
200 TYPE is now 8-bit binary
CWD /public_html
250 OK. Current directory is /public_html
PWD
257 "/public_html" is your current location
CWD /public_html
250 OK. Current directory is /public_html
SYST
215 UNIX Type: L8
PASV
227 Entering Passive Mode (***,***,***,***,193,110)
QUIT
221-Goodbye. You uploaded 0 and downloaded 0 kbytes.
221 Logout.
```

Any idea what happen or how to solve it?

Comment: Is the `54.36.225.212` the correct IP address of your FTP server?

Comment: I'm guessing it is firewall problem as the server is rejecting the passive port the client is trying to connect. Or maybe you should use active connection mode.

Are you using TLS encryption(FTPS) or just plain FTP? FTPS is sometimes problematic as firewalls cannot determine which port is used in passive FTP (cannot read the requests)

Answer (score 0):

in my case I solved by deselecting "passive mode" in the Remote Connection configuration

[image]